# Cannot set arguments for go app during debugging

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I'm trying to debug my goland app and have some problems with launch.json file. My app should be run with argument:  my_go_app -c path_to_config.

My launch.json looks like:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch my go app",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "launch",
            "mode": "auto",
            "program": "${fileDirname}",
            "args": ["-c /home/roman/projects/myapp/some.json"]
        }
    ]
}
```

But when I debug app I have received the following error:

flag provided but not defined: -c /home/roman/projects/myapp/some.json
Usage of /tmp/__debug_bin542579318:
-c string
Specify the configuration file. (default "config.json")

Without debugging my app runs with success. Please explain what is wrong...

Answer (score 2):

I have found where is problem. The json should be like this:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch my go app",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "launch",
            "mode": "auto",
            "program": "${fileDirname}",
            "args": ["-c",  "/home/roman/projects/myapp/some.json"]
        }
    ]
}
```